# Raspberry-Pi live streaming using web cam

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, microprocessors, raspberry-pi2

I am new with RASPBERRY PI . But i've successfully completed a project with the use of Brick Pi which is actually a WIFI based moving car. Now i want to enable live camera streaming to my project. Can i do it using my USB webcam ?
I actually want to stream it on any browser.
If YES, how can i achieve it ?

Is there any better solution than using a webcam ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install [MJPG-streamer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mjpg-streamer/) on your Rasperry Pi

`sudo apt-get install libjpeg8-dev imagemagick libv4l-dev`

`sudo ln -s /usr/include/linux/videodev2.h /usr/include/linux/videodev.h`

`git clone https://github.com/jacksonliam/mjpg-streamer.git`

and then you can use a command like this:

`mjpg_streamer -i “/usr/local/lib/input_uvc.so" -o “/usr/local/lib/output_http.so -p 9000 -w www”`

You can check out [this](http://www.tinkernut.com/portfolio/homemade-remote-controlled-spycam/) tutorial by Tinkernut, which basicly does what you want as well as some other cool stuff